# Allow OPs to see deleted answers on their questions

Tags: feature-request, deleted-answers

There are a lot of questions here about people being able to see their *own* deleted posts.  This is not that.

Sometimes when I ask a question on a site where I don't have 10k rep, I'll get a notification of an answer, go to read it -- and find nothing, because it was deleted.  Often that means the community deleted it as low-quality or spam, but sometimes it's for some other reason -- self-deleted, or it was good information but *not an answer*, for example.

Sometimes the OP asks about this ([immediate prompt for this question](https://interpersonal.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2258/106)).  I've been asked occasionally about my self-deletions, and as a moderator I'm asked somewhat frequently about deleted answers.

We all have an interest in the question but the OP has a *bigger* interest.  Could we allow the OP to see deleted answers to his question regardless of his rep?  The interface would be exactly the same as for 10k users.  Some behaviors are already different for the OP (for example, commenting on all answers), so it seems feasible to check not just reputation but post ownership.  If that's too expensive, though, then maybe we could add some sort of "click to see deleted answers" for the OP if there are deleted answers?  I'm looking for a way to satisfy the OP's curiosity without having to ask 10k users or moderators about it.

Comment: @Catija *sigh*.  Why do these things never come up in search?  (I don't just mean the search box, which is notoriously bad, but also the list of suggestions based on title.)  Well, one thing is that the dupe's title doesn't imply FR but discussion, but that's easily fixed.

Comment: Yeah, I know what you mean. :P

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2645/show-all-of-my-question-answers-to-me-even-if-they-are-deleted would be of interest too

Comment: @JourneymanGeek yes, that's the flipside -- show me *my* deleted stuff.  Here I'm asking about stuff *other people wrote to me* that was deleted.

Comment: pretty sure you can see everything, as long as there's a post by you somewhere. but ugh, might also be cause I'm 10k + in most sites I bother with these things on

Comment: Yes, that's because you're 10k.  On sites where I'm 10k I can see those answers, but on ones where I'm not I can't, even on my own questions.   That's why a lower-rep user asked the meta question I linked to; he remembered a helpful answer that he could no longer see.